# Java Script Email Validation troubles without Regex

Tags: javascript

I am working on a lab for school where we create a function that validates that the email textbox value is a valid email structure (xyx@xyz.xyz). I am having trouble figuring out how it will work I am typing it in VS code and I'm not really getting anywhere when I load the page on Live Server. I am very new to JS so I feel like I am not implementing my function properly. Also, I used a simple Regex email pattern but am curious about how I can validate it with just vanilla javascript. Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

```
function validate(){
  var email = document.getElementById("email").value;
  var error = "";
  const emailPattern =/\S+@\S+\.\S+/;

  if(email.value.match(emailPattern))
  {
    return true;
  }
  else if(email.value == ""){
    error = "You entered a blank email address. \n";
    alert(error);
    return false;
  }
  else
  {
    error = "You have entered an invalid email address!";
    alert(error);
    return false;
  }
```

Comment: without regex, you'd start by splitting the string on `@` ensuring the result has length of 2 ... then you'd split the second result using `.` and ensure that result has a length of 2 as well ... personally I'd check that the second split has a length of at least 2 ... you also want to make sure there's no spaces in the string at all

Comment: the issue with your email pattern by the way is that `@` is a valid `\S` - so @@@.@ would match

Answer (score 1):

Creating a good regex for email is quite difficult for a novice because the email specification is quite permissive you can have multiple dots before and after the @ and that's beside various disallowed characters.
You can google for proper regexes for email if required.

But you have multiple problems with your function besides the regex.
First your function block is not closed, you need to add another curly bracket at the end.

Here because you use ".value" Property you get a string with the actual email entered in the input field.

```
var email = document.getElementById("email").value;
```

But here you try to use the "email" variable as if it is the reference to the input object when it is in reality a string and does not have the ".value" Property.

```
if(email.value.match(emailPattern))
```

You should drop the .value and just use

```
if(email.match(emailPattern))
```

you make the same mistake in other places were you use the email variable.
Here is the corrected code with a naive regex for email matching.

```js
function validate(){
  const email = document.getElementById("email").value;
  let error = "";
  const emailPattern =/\w+@\w+\.\w+/;

  if(email.match(emailPattern)){
    console.log(`Your email ${email} is marvelous`);
    return true;
  }
  else if(email == ""){
    error = "You entered a blank email address. \n";
    alert(error);
    return false;
  }
  else {
    error = "You have entered an invalid email address!";
    alert(error);
    return false;
  }
}
```

```html
<input id="email" type="text" value="">
<button onclick="validate()">Validate</button>
```

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. It makes more sense to me know that the value doesn't need to be in the condition because it is already the variable.

Comment: Glad I could help. Did it solve your problems or do you need other clarifications?